# "to delete" vs "to be deleted"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, infinitives

Are both of these correct?

> 1. The email address of the Facebook account to delete is user@example.com.
> 2. The email address of the Facebook account to be deleted is user@example.

In case #1 is correct, does it mean the same as #2? #2 appears to be a passive voice construction. In case #1 is correct, what type of sentence/clause construction is it or how do we call it?

Comment: As is? Because there's no verb in sentence 1.... so do you want them to be considered as phrases or as full sentences?

Comment: Neither one of these is a complete sentence.

Comment: @J.R. yeah... I was just realizing that. :/ So I think we need some more information.

Comment: @Catija - If I had a nickel for every time I saw a question asking "Which of these sentences is correct?", and the samples given weren't even complete sentences, then I could probably buy an overpriced grande coffee at Starbucks – assuming the cashier would take all those nickels. (To the OP: please give more [details, context, and research](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)...)

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question. Are these complete sentences now? Thanks

Comment: @J.R.: It's worse than you think: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6678/2303

Comment: The suit to clean...the suit to be cleaned.  Yes, either way.  The question to ask...the question to be asked...

Answer (score 1):

We call it an *Infinitival Relative Clause (hereafter, IRC)*. Or if you don't want to analyze it as a relative clause, you can just call it  a *post-modifing infinitival clause*. This IRC is so flexible that it can occur with either a passive voice or an active voice. This is explained by Biber et al. in *Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English.*

> Postmodifying to-clauses are more flexible than participle clauses for two 
>   reasons: they can occur with both subject and non-subject gaps [...]

- The e-mail address of the Facebook account to delete
  <sub>(This is in the active voice. The object of the verb *delete* is missing, so this IRC has a non-subject gap.)</sub>
- The e-mail address of the Facebook account to be deleted
  <sub>(This is in the passive voice. The subject of the infinitival clause is missing, so this IRC has a subject gap.)</sub>